# How to show all the failures in Junit Assertions

Tags: java, junit, assertion

My requirement is to show all the failures after Junit test run.

I tried two things:

**Assertions.assertEquals** --> This stops the execution after first failure, and in test report I see only first failure.

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expceted, actual,"Error Message");
```

**assertj.SoftAssertions** --> Here execution happens but in test report I do not see any failure message.

```
SoftAssertions softAssertions = new SoftAssertions();
softAssertions.assertThat(expected).withFailMessage("Error Message", actual) ;
```

Any Idea if any other type of assertion or any other option I can use with these assertions?

I tried Junit5 **assertAll**

```
for (int index = 0; index < response1.row.size(); index++)
        {
            int finalIndex = index;
            Assertions.assertAll(
                    () ->Assertions.assertEquals(Response1.row.get(finalIndex).field1, Response2.row.get(finalIndex).field1,
                            "Value doesn't match between source and target"),
                    () ->Assertions.assertEquals(Response1.row.get(finalIndex).field2, Response2.row.get(finalIndex).field2,
                            "Value doesn't match between source and target"),
                    () ->Assertions.assertEquals(Response1.row.get(finalIndex).field3, Response2.row.get(finalIndex).field3,
                            "Value doesn't match between source and target")
        }
```

But here it shows failures only for first row, not for all the rows.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit 5 added `assertAll`:

```
assertAll(
        () -> assertEquals(...),
        () -> assertTrue(...)
        // etc
);
```

It takes any number of lambdas, and if I recall correctly each lambda can even throw exceptions. That means you can delegate to methods:

```
assertAll(
        ...
        complexAssertion(...)
);

...

private void complexAssertion(...) throws IOException {
    String expectedOutput = <read resource>;
    SomeException thrown = assertThrows(SomeException.class, () -> ...);
    assertInstanceOf(SomeOtherException.class, thrown.getCause());
    // nested assertAll can also be used!
}
```

Edit: using `assertAll` inside `assertAll`, made difficult because of the index:

```
// assuming that response1.row and response2.row have equal sizes
assertAll(IntStream.range(0, reponse1.row.size())
        .mapToObj(index -> () -> {
            assertAll(
                assertEquals(response1.row.get(index).field1, response2.row.get(index).field1, "message");
                // etc
            );
        })
);
```

The `mapToObj` may need a cast to `Execution`, perhaps extracted to another method.

Comment: hmm... This works if we have multiple mismatches for same records. But in my case I am trying to assert multiple mismatches for multiple records in a loop. So for example, in first record I have 3 mismatches and in second record I have 2 mismatches. assertAll detects only 3 mismatches of first record. But my requirement is to print all the failures.

Comment: May be my previous comment wasn't clear, that's why I updated the code as well in my question for assertAll.

Comment: `assertAll` can take the executors as varargs but also as Collection or Stream. That means you can use `assertAll` inside `assertAll`. The index makes this a bit more complex, but it's still doable. I've updated my answer to include something that shows how this should more or less look like.

Comment: Thanks Rob.. I was able to apply based on your suggestion. Many Thanks!!!